# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String' when comparing two long values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a MySQL schema containing a table Medical_Record which has a long NHSNumber value. In my dotnet project, I have created a Medical_Record class with a long value for NHSNumber and have also successfully created a DB Context for it. In my controller class, I am comparing this value to a parameter id which is also a long, however I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. Not sure why this is happening, I've checked everything multiple times.

```
public class Medical_Record
    {
        [Key]
        public int doseNo { get; set; }
        public long NHSNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime VaccinationDate { get; set; }
        public string? VaccineManufacturer { get; set; }
        public string? DiseaseTargeted { get; set; }
        public string? VaccineType { get; set; }
        public string? Product { get; set; }
        public string? VaccineBatchNo { get; set; }
        public string? CountryOfVaccination { get; set; }
        public string? Authority { get; set; }
        public string? Site { get; set; }
        public int TotalSeriesOfDoses { get; set; }
        public string? DisplayName { get; set; }
        public int SnomedCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
        public int ProcedureCode { get; set; }
        public sbyte Booster { get; set; }
                
        public int vaccineId { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public DbSet<Medical_Record> Medical_Record { get; set; }
```

```
[HttpGet("PatientVaccines")]
       
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPatientVaccines(long id)
        {
            var medicalRecords = await _govUkDBContext.Medical_Record.Where(x => (long)x.NHSNumber == id).ToListAsync();

            if (medicalRecords == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(medicalRecords);
        }
```

and my database is something like this

[image: image of table structure]

I have tried explicit casting for both variables, double checking the data types and I am still receiving this error. Not sure if its coming from this because id is an int64 and NHSNumber should be as well however it mentions int32 and string.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: On what line does your error occur

Comment: I'm pretty sure the NHS number should always be a string. It may contain digits but, like a phone number, it's actually a string of digits, not a numeric value.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `medicalRecords` will never be null. If there are no matching returns, `ToList()` should turn it into an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VaccineBatchNo` is a string in the class definition:

```
 public string? VaccineBatchNo { get; set; }
```

But it is an `int` in the database:

[image]

Comment: That was definitely the problem. Thank you!